# PayPal IPN not work after payment

Tags: php, paypal

i have a problem with PayPal IPN.

I'm trying to test with sandbox, but it is as if it does not recognize the ipn.php file after payment.

I create a form that send the info to PayPal and 3 files:

```
name="return" -> confirm.php (work after payment)
name="cancel_return" -> cancel.php (work after payment)
name="notify_url" -> ipn.php (this not work after payment)
```

I'm using 2 file from PayPal guide:

PaypalIPN.php -> link: https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/php/PaypalIPN.php

and ipn.php -> link: https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/php/example_usage_advanced.php

I activated my account IPN from paypal website.

After the payment on paypal i return on file confirm.php, if i cancel the payment on paypal i return on file cancel.php, but ipn.php not work.

Can you help me please?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you tried setting the IPN address in your account?

Comment: What doesn't work? Is it not going to the URL? Does it hit the URL but the script has issues? Check your access logs and error logs on your webserver.

Comment: yes, i added the file url in IPN settings from my account: http://www.example.com/folder/ipn.php

Answer (score 0):

I just finished fighting through this process a few days ago. You can ditch paypal's guide because I fought with it and it didn't take me where I needed to go. Instead I would try this: https://gist.github.com/xcommerce-gists/3440401#file-completelistener-php 
Also, you don't need to send the files with the form, all of that information can be placed in the button specifics, etc on the paypal site. You can place the url of your ipn.php file on the IPN simulator on paypals site and use that to play with your listener. Note that if any of the backend processes under the VERIFIED section are incorrect, the listener will not return a handshake, so test your php code out first before applying it. 
 Other than that I'd have to see your actual code to help trouble shoot more.